# Why is this custom network-service crashing (written in C)?

Tags: c, debugging, network-programming

I wrote this program which listens on a given port and then, once a connection is received, outputs a single line of text and disconnects.  It runs for days, processing thousands of queries, but then (inevitably) crashes and I have to go restart it.  Wondering if anyone sees anything wrong with it, or (alternatively) if anyone can suggest a way to make it more robust.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     srand(time(0));

     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0)
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

   while (1)
   {
     unsigned char write_val;
     unsigned char y[BYTES];
     int i, j;

     newsockfd = accept(sockfd,
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0)
          error("ERROR on accept");

     fill_buffer(y);  // fills buffer y with a 128-bit string; not included here
     for (i=BYTES-1; i >= 0; i--)
     {
       const void* ZERO = (void *)"0";
       const void* ONE  = (void *)"1";

       for (j=7; j >= 0; j--)
         write(newsockfd, (y[i] >> j) & 1 ? ONE : ZERO, 1);
     }

     write(newsockfd, "\n", 1);
     close(newsockfd);
   }

   close(sockfd);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I presume you've tried it in a debugger?

Comment: @Benj `"0"` isn't a char, it's a string (which in C is `(char *)`).  I'm casting this `char*` to `void*` because that's the pointer type expected by `write()`.

Comment: why don't you do `char c = '0'; write(...,(void*)&c);`

Answer (score 2):

> anyone sees anything wrong with it

While this code could be made more efficient (by writing all the bytes in one single pass for example), there's no obvious flaw there.

That makes the unpublished part of your code a decent candidate for the problem:

```
fill_buffer(y);  // fills buffer y with a 128-bit string; not included here
```

If you read more bytes than `y[]`'s size then you will crash.

> or (alternatively) if anyone can suggest a way to make it more robust

Try enlarging the size of this `y[]` buffer (doubling it can't hurt).

And make sure that `fill_buffer()` can't read more than `BYTES` characters.

Publish this missing code in case of doubt.

You could also compile your code with debug symbols and dump a backtrace (with symbols) in a file from your signal handler. This way, if your program crashes, you will know `where` and `why`.

Comment: I assume "flow" should be "flaw"?  Or is something amiss with program flow?  Also, `fill_buffer()` doesn't read bytes: it simply fills `y[]` with 16 bytes and returns.  Finally, I have been running this program in the background and then logging out; I've just restarted it using `screen` so I can see if anything's printed when the program ends unexpectedly.

Comment: Thanks for the typo, now corrected in the reply. There's no alternative to a signal handler and a backtrace to see where the crash will start and florish.

Comment: just make sure you have core dumps enabled, you'll be able to analyze the core dump with a debugger after crash.  But the problem is most likely the size of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks good with some comments.
One somewhat important comment:
portno should be declared as unsigned short. This works OK with an Intel-like (little endian) processor but it won't be portable to a processor with different endianness.

Anyway it was not the reason for your process crashing.

Obviously the crash occurs while executing within the 'while', and by looking at the code, if it crashes for a buffer overflow, the only possibility is within fill_buffer.

If you show the definition of BYTES and fill_buffer it will be easier to help you.

Now, if it is not a buffer overflow, there is the possibility that it aborts in the write if the client closed the connection before the server writes into the socket. In that case the process will receive a signal SIGPIPE and it will abort if the code does not handle that signal.

You can also ignore SIGPIPE with:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Other possibility is if you are doing something weird with write_val and you're not showing that code.

I hope this helps.